# How to send cookie in request to API In php via Curl

Tags: php, http, curl, cookies, request

I am having HTTP cookie based Authentication,After Authentication i get cookie in response,

Another step is to send cookie in request to API. along with post/get request

Below Example is of my Curl

```
$cookie_jar= $_COOKIE['DesigntoolAuth'];
//$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
// The data to send to the API
$postData = array(
    'ProjectId' => $projectId,
    'ProjectName' => $proname,
    'ProjectDetails' => $details, 
    'UserId' => $userId
);

$data_string = json_encode($postData);  
// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json'                                                                             
    //'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
    ));                                                                   

    $api_result =  curl_exec($ch);
    echo $api_result;
```

Can Anybody tell how ti send the cookie ?

Comment: The `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` (as the name implied) needs to be a file which contains your cookies you need to send.

Comment: Needs to be file ? i didnt get this ? should i need to send my cookie value to $cookie_jar ?

Answer (score 0):

From [the cURL PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE
>
> The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but cookie handling is still enabled.

This means that the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` needs to refer to a file which contains the cookies you need to send. The file is a file which exists on the server running cURL, which, in turn, will transmit the cookie data to the remote host. I'd expect read access to be required on the file.

A good answer describing how the Netscape format looks like can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36531/format-of-cookies-when-using-wget)

In addition, if you want to keep the cookies that are generated during the request, you also need to set a `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.

Comment: Hey I am Sorry, couldnt able to understand it, as i am new to this! Well how will i get "The name of the file containing the cookie data" well i am receaving cookies from other domain, i am not creating it, bcz i have authentication on other domain, which redirects me to subdomain after successfull login.

Comment: The file is a local file, cURL will use that file to read cookies and transmit them to the other domain. You just need to create the file on the server which cURL is running on.